# How to call copy constructor of class having parameterised only

Tags: c++, inheritance

```cpp
class Traveler {
  private:
     string name;
     
  public:
    // only parameterised constuctor allowed
    Traveler(string _name) {
      name = _name;
    }
    
    Traveler(Traveler &T) {
      name = T.name;
    }   
    
    Traveler operator=(const Traveler& T) {
      Traveler temp("");
      temp.name = T.name;
      return temp;
    } 
    
};
```

```cpp
class Pager {
  
  private :
    string message;
    
  public:
    // only parameterised constuctor allowed
    Pager(string _message) {
      message = _message;
    }
    
    Pager(Pager &P) {
      message = P.message;
    }
    
    Pager operator=(const Pager &P) {
      Pager temp("");
      temp.message = P.message;
      return temp;
    }
    
  
};
```

```cpp
class BusinessTraveler : public Traveler {
  private:
      string name;
      Pager pager;
      
  public:
     
     // parameterised constructor not working 
     BusinessTraveler(string _name): Traveler(_name),pager(_name){
       name = _name;
     }
    
    // copy constrcutor  not working 
     BusinessTraveler(BusinessTraveler &BT) {
       pager = BT.pager;
       name = BT.name;
     }
      
    // default constructor
     BusinessTraveler():Traveler(""),pager(""){
       name = ""
       
     }
     
    //  BusinessTraveler operator=(const BusinessTraveler &B) {
    //   BusinessTraveler bt;
    //   bt.name = B.name;
    //   bt.pager = B.pager;
    //   return bt;
    // }    
};
```

Here I have three classes. `Traveler` and `Pager have parameterized constructors only. And` BusinessTraverler`is inherited by`Traveler`only, but has a member of class`Pager`.` BusinessTraveler` has all three constructors (default, copy, and parameterized).

I need help implementing the copy constructor in `BusinessTraveler`. It throws an error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘Traveler::Traveler()’
      BusinessTraveler(BusinessTraveler &BT) {
```

Comment: I am confused. You seem to know about constructor initializer list, but you didn't try providing arguments for constructors of members of your class there. Why? E.g. `BusinessTraveler(string _name): Traveler(_name), pager ("")`.

Comment: help to do what? What is the meaning of "not working" ? Please include the error message in the question

Comment: i tried to pass as initialiser list also , but it throws error ```type ‘Pager’ is not a direct base of ‘BusinessTraveler’```

Comment: i tried to pass as initialiser list also , but it throws error ```type ‘Pager’ is not a direct base of ‘BusinessTraveler’```

Comment: @DeepakSharma Use `pager ("")` in member initializer list, not `Pager ("")`.

Comment: Is it intended for a `BusinessTraveler` to have two `name` fields, `BusinessTraveler::name` and `Traveler::name`, instead of just using the one inherited from `Traveler`?

Comment: Also is it intended for `operator=` to return a new `Traveler`, `Pager`, etc. instance instead of mutating the left hand side of the assignment operator?

Comment: Any idea why we have > 50 code lines to find a initializer list?

Comment: @songyuanyao , i did in your your way . still copy constructor is at throwing error

Comment: @DeepakSharma Did you write it like `BusinessTraveler(BusinessTraveler &BT) : name(BT.name), pager(BT.pager) {}`? And better changing all the copy constructors' parameter to reference to `const`, e.g. `Pager(const Pager &P) ...`.

Comment: yeah...That worked ...Thanks..this was a great learning today

Comment: @songyuanyao Shouldn't that be `... : Traveler(BT), name(BT.name), ...` so that the base class is copied as well? Or is that done automatically?

Comment: @NathanPierson Yes, you're right. @DeepakSharma It should be `BusinessTraveler(BusinessTraveler &BT) : Traveler(BT), name(BT.name), pager(BT.pager) {}`.

Comment: Just let the compiler do the work: `BusinessTraveler(BusinessTraveler const&) = default;`

Comment: Coolest way to do this..Thanks

Comment: Why do your assignment operators create a new object then return by value? They're supposed to assign to the _current_ object.

Answer (score 0):

The idea was to pass the object as intialisation list along with the constructors defining

adding below statement in default and paramterised const.

```
BusinessTraveler(string _name): Traveler(_name), pager (name) {}
```

```
BusinessTraveler(): Traveler(""), pager ("") {}
```

Adding below statement in copy const.

```
BusinessTraveler(BusinessTraveler &BT) : Traveler(BT), name(BT.name), pager(BT.pager) {}
```

Comment: You're going in the wrong direction. If each of these things needs a name, then not having a default constructor is _good_. Instead of adding one, find a way to remove your need for it, because it's likely an inappropriate need.